# Modified Bessel Function of the First Kind: Changing the Limits of the Integral

Tags: integration, special-functions

Can anyone explain why:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\exp(\beta(2r_{1}r_{2}\cos(\theta)))\,\mathrm d\theta=2\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}\exp(\beta(2r_{1}r_{2}\cos(\theta)))\,\mathrm d\theta\right)$$

where the right hand side is the modified Bessel function of the first kind evaluated at $2r_{1}r_{2}\beta$ - here's the function for convenience:

$$I_{0}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\exp(x\cos\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$$

Comment: note: the factor of 1/pi is gone - the right hand side uses the modified bessel function of the first kind, but actually the exact integral representation is:

Comment: The function $f(\theta)=\cos\theta$ (and therefore $g(\theta)=\exp\{ a\cos\theta\}$ as well) is symmetric with respect to the vertical line $\theta=\pi$. Therefore, $\int_{0}^{\pi}g = \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}g $.

Comment: Thanks, that was obvious. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at a plot of $\cos{\theta}$: $\cos{\theta}$ takes on exactly the same set of values in $[0,\pi]$ as it does in $[\pi,2 \pi]$.  Therefore, the integrals over these regions are equal and the equality is true.

Comment: Of course! Thanks for this X

Comment: @AlexanderGiles: you're welcome.  If you found this solution useful, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark to the left.